# Ignore EditText setOnClickListener code to be able to edit text

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have an EditText as a text field to accept a telephone number amongst other personal details on an activity.

On activity launch the EditText is disabled until the user selects edit to edit the information. It is then enabled and allows the user to type a number in it.

Once the user clicks to save the data the EditText is made unfocusable using

```
txtPhone.setFocusable(false);
```

It then uses an onClickListener to allow the user to click it and call the number it contains.

When the user clicks edit to edit the number, I am setting

```
txtPhone.setFocusable(true);
```

To allow the EditText to receive focus however it is still seems to be using the onClickListener and won't allow the text to be edited giving the warning in log cat:

```
TextView does not support text selection. Action mode canceled.
```

Code for the EditText listener:

```
txtPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(txtPhone.isFocusable()==false)
            {
                if(txtPhone.getText().length() > 1)
                {
                    // Call number
                    // Using Toast to show listeners working first          
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Calling... " + txtPhone.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The EditText xml:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ems="10"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:hint="Telephone..."
     android:inputType="phone"
     android:maxLength="11" />
```

How can I make it so that the text is editable like on first launch and ignore the listener but when not focusable call the number, I don't seem to be able to get it to work as desired

Comment: I get that you are trying to implement a smooth/sleek interface with a unique design, but wouldn't this be tons easier with an edit text field and a button that just says call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the warning you were getting, but wasn't able to get the Toast to appear on pressing the textbox when not focused. I did try the following to replicate what you're trying to achieve. Hopefully I understood you correctly.

**EditText**

Instead of using `enabled="false"` I used `focusable="false"`. This will have a similar behaviour to enabled being false, but allows the `onClickListener` of `txtPhone` to fire.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="Telephone..."
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:maxLength="11" />
```

**Listeners**

Since you didn't show code for the buttons, I used a button called `btnEdit` to switch between focuses. Instead of `txtPhone.setFocusable(true);` I used `txtPhone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` to properly get the edit text to be editable.

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (txtPhone.isFocusable()) {
            txtPhone.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            txtPhone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
    }
});

txtPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (txtPhone.isFocusable() == false) {
            if (txtPhone.getText().length() > 1) {
                // Call number
                // Using Toast to show listeners working first
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calling... " + txtPhone.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So when I first start the activity, `txtPhone` is not editable. When I click the edit button, `txtPhone` becomes editable and I am able to enter numbers. Lastly, I click the edit button again to disable `txtPhone` and when I press on it, the Toast appears.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you very much for that txtPhone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); was the part I needed but didn't know about its use :D